# Conversion Struts2 tags to SpringMVC using JSTL TAGS

Tags: spring-mvc, struts2, jstl

Due some security reasons needs to convert Struts2 tags to Springmvc. There is any utility to do this conversion?we are going to use JSTL tags?The Struts Developer may not be define  in one line.How to read each of Struts tags, its parameters and convert into JSLT tags? If am start write our own utility , how get each struts tags pattern and  convert?

Comment: 1) What security issues specifically? It'd likely be easier to upgrade your S2 install than to re-write an application. 2) It's unlikely this process could be trivially automated.

Comment: am doing POC on this conversion ..when i want to use  <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld"     prefix="html"  %> in springMVC , application says Exception caught java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found.. Some site says adding ActionServlet  in load-startup will resolve the issue. There is any other way without Load ActionServlet ?. If you load Actionservlet then struts-config.xml should be there ins web-inf.